# Assigning a custom view to left UIBarButtonItem hides UINavigationItem title

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I have a tableviewcontroller with a navigation bar item. I created a nib with a custom view. If I assign it to the left bar button, the title hides/ doesn't load. I tried manually adding titles, after loading the view, that doesn't work either.

[image]

[image]

Most work is done in the storyboard, with the exception of the left button.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NavigationBarLeftItem" owner:self options:nil];
leftNavBarItem = [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem initWithCustomView:navBarleftItemView];
```

I tried setting the title with

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.title = @"Today";
```

and

```
self.title = @"Today";
```

but no avail.

Comment: it would be useful to see some code

Comment: How much big is the frame of your custom view?

Comment: thank you. added some code. Is there anything I should have done while setting "leftNavBarItem" ?

Comment: @GiuseppeIacobucci I did not set any; from what I understand, there is no need to set... Am I wrong?

Comment: Try to set navBarleftItemView.frame.size to 20x20 just for testing and tell us what appens.
Another thing if you don't load and set the custom view, you can see the title? Just for know if there is some other problem.

Comment: @GiuseppeIacobucci for the second question, yes, i can. let me try your suggestion...

Comment: Sorry Man, but in the image you posted there is set a title: "Title".
So just use this line of code: self.navigationItem.title  = "Title you want" in viewDidLoad

Comment: hey, thank you very much. setting it to "title" was intentional. But the frame suggestion worked. Well, I wanted it to do that adaptively, from what I read iOS should do that, but this should work for now. I feel stupid for not trying that out. Thank you for your help...

Comment: Nothing, best regards.